# how can I sum all rows according to grouping of another column in R using dplyr?

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr

I have a data frame that looks like this :

| name | var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| a | 1 | 10 | -1 |
| a | 2 | 20 | -2 |
| a | 3 | 30 | -3 |
| b | 4 | 40 | -4 |
| b | 5 | 50 | -5 |
| b | 6 | 60 | -6 |
| c | 7 | 70 | -7 |
| c | 8 | 80 | -8 |
| c | 9 | 90 | -9 |

I want to sum of the sub matrices according to name variable but rowwise in one matrix keeping the column name. (Not to sum all the values in the group a or b).

ideally I want the resulted data frame to look like this :

| var1 | var2 | var3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12 | 120 | -12 |
| 15 | 150 | -15 |
| 18 | 180 | -18 |

how can I do this in R using dplyr ?

```
 library(tidyverse)
name = c(rep("a",3),rep("b",3),rep("c",3))
var1 = seq(1,9,1);var1
var2 = seq(10,90,10);var2
var3 = seq(-1,-9,-1);var3
A = tibble(name,var1,var2,var3);A
```

Comment: I put an answer that I came up after the question is closed: `map_dfr(.x=c(1,2,0),~slice(A,which(row_number()%%3==.x))|>summarise(across(var1:var3,sum)))`

Comment: @CarlosLuisRivera when I run your answer R reported me the following : `Error in `as_mapper()`:
! Can't convert `.f`, a <tbl_df/tbl/data.frame> object, to a
  function.`

Comment: why you deleted my question ? the suggested answers from previous posts are not equivalent

Comment: I did not close your question, rather I flagged your question to reopen it. Not only you but I don't know why other moderators/users closed your question.

Comment: @CarlosLuisRivera thank you for that.I cannot understand why someone votes to close a question that believes there is an answer somewhere else.I tried it.I searched for a question.I didn't find one so a make a post.

Comment: I'm not sure why my code throw any error, since the code works in my environment. I use  `tibble  3.1.8`, `dplyr   1.0.10`, and `purrr   0.3.4` on R 4.2.0. What is the version number of these three packages on your environment? What verseon of R are you using?

Comment: @CarlosLuisRivera on `R version 4.1.1 (2021-08-10)` I run `tibble_3.1.7` , `dplyr_1.0.9` and `purrr_0.3.4`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248842/discussion-between-carlos-luis-rivera-and-homer-jay-simpson).

Comment: @CarlosLuisRivera speechless.Thank you for your help.You are awesome.Still the question remains deleted.hahahha